# SQL or Tableau Replace values with existing one with reference to another field

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, tableau-api

My problem with the data is

```
Id  Name
--------
1   a
2   b
1   a
1   a
1   NULL
2   b
2   b
2   NULL
2   b
2   NULL
```

ID is unique to the name

I would like the NULL values to be replaced with existing Records.
Or if there are any other alternatives

I have about 2000 IDs so it needs to be automated.

Comment: Your question risks being downvoted/closed due to a lack of clarity in your question. Please consider rewording to make it more clear what you are asking. See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below query can use to replace the `NULL`s with its Id's `Name`, since `Id` is unique to the `Name`.

```
UPDATE T1 SET T1.Name = T2.ValidName
FROM TestTable T1 
JOIN (  SELECT Id, MAX(Name) AS ValidName
        FROM TestTable
        WHERE Name IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY Id ) T2 ON T2.Id = T1.Id
WHERE T1.Name IS NULL
```

Sample execution in SQL-Server:

```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE (Id INT, Name VARCHAR (20));

INSERT INTO @TestTable (Id, Name) VALUES
(1, 'a'),
(2, 'b'),
(1, 'a'),
(1, 'a'),
(1, NULL),
(2, 'b'),
(2, 'b'),
(2, NULL),
(2, 'b'),
(2, NULL);

UPDATE T1 SET T1.Name = T2.ValidName
FROM @TestTable T1 
JOIN (  SELECT Id, MAX(Name) AS ValidName
        FROM @TestTable
        WHERE Name IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY Id ) T2 ON T2.Id = T1.Id
WHERE T1.Name IS NULL

SELECT * FROM @TestTable
```

Comment: Thanks it worked,  I replace the last where clause with  = ' ' instead of null as they were blanks and not NULL values

Answer (score 0):

try this:  replace with your tablename

```
declare @id int, @name varchar(10)
declare c cursor for
select distinct id,name from  <table> where id is not null and name is not null
open c
fetch next from c into @id,@name
while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
begin
update <table> set name=@name where id=@id
fetch next from c into @id,@name
end
close c
deallocate c
```